# $f \in C^1([a;b])$, prove that $ \forall x,y \in [a;b]$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)| < || f' ||_2 \sqrt{|x-y|} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

#### Question:

Let $f \in C^1([a;b])$, prove that $ \forall x,y \in [a;b]$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)| < || f' ||_2 \sqrt{|x-y|} $

#### Answer:

1- $f \in C^1([a;b]) \Rightarrow f'(\chi) $ exists and is defined: $ |f(x)-f(y)|= |\int_x ^y f'(\chi) d \chi | \leq \int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| d \chi$ by triangle inequality.

2- Now pay attention to the fact that by definition $|\int_x ^y f'(\chi) d \chi | \geq 0$ and that $\int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| d \chi \geq 0$. And as $x^2$ is an increasing function for $x \geq 0$ we have that if $|\int_x ^y f'(\chi) d \chi | \leq \int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| d \chi$ then $(\int_x ^y f'(\chi) d \chi )^2 = (|\int_x ^y f'(\chi) d \chi |)^2 \leq (\int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| d \chi)^2$

But from here I am stuck can somebody help me please?

Comment: Think Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank for your comment. I ve writing an answer can you please tell me if it is correct now?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3904462/42969

Comment: @MartinR thank i am going to read it.

Comment: Side note: Use `\Vert` or `\|` for norm signs, that looks much better than `||` .

Comment: @MartinR thk can you tell me if my answer is correct please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of the comment of  https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4829/jose27

3- We continue by writing $(\int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| d \chi)^2 = (\int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| \cdot 1 d \chi)^2 $ thus we can identify the following inner product $\int_x ^y |f'(\chi)| \cdot 1 d \chi = \left<|f'(\chi)| | 1 \right> $

4- By CS inequality we have that $ | \left<|f'(\chi)| | 1 \right> | \leq \| f'(\chi) \|_2 \|1\|_2 = \| f'(\chi) \|_2 \sqrt{\int_x ^y 1^2 d \chi} = \| f'(\chi) \|_2 \sqrt{|x-y|}$

Q.E.D.

Comment: up, is this correct?

Comment: It's mostly correct, though for readability purposes I'd write, when you switch to norms, the explicit interval over which we're integrating (first over $[x,y]$ to handle the $1$ term, and then going to $[a,b]$ by monotonicity of the integral to handle the $f'$ term).